# Can't unload native macOS Mojave apache using launchctl

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, webserver, macos-mojave

I have a fresh installation of MacOS Mojave 10.14. I'm trying to shutdown and remove auto-loading scripts for apache.

```
$ httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.34 (Unix)
Server built:   Aug 17 2018 16:29:43

$ sudo apachectl stop

$ sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist 2>/dev/null
```

After rebooting, I open the browser and go to localhost and still shows "It works!". What should I do to make the OS to stop launching apache on reboot? Am I missing something?

Comment: Why are you discarding errors from the `sudo launchctl unload` command? What does it print if you run it *without* discarding error output?

Comment: I've tried without discarding the errors from `unload` as well, I wasn't getting any output either. I restarted my computer many times and apache was still running and I had a response in the browser. Curiously, today I booted my computer (I actually turned off/on) and apache was not running. I have no clue why it was still loading after restarting.

Comment: have you ever install apache(httpd) with homebrew? in such way, there could be multiple apache servers on your mac

Answer (score -1):

When I run the command …
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
… I receive the following error:

/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service

Trying to delete the file manually fails, too; so I believe this is protected by SIP.  I was able to disable SIP, and the command still didn't work.  I just deleted the plist file to keep the process from starting.  That's probably NOT the preferred method.